# 2003 Buick Rendezvous overheating without steam, coolant overflow at normal temperature

Tags: coolant, overheating

My car overheats to the max, the heater will not heat even in full blast. When the car overheats there is no steam or boiling coolant. The radiator has antifreeze and the reservoir is overflowing. I don't know what could be causing this problem, please help.

Comment: What is giving you the indication that the car is overheating? When you say the reservoir is overflowing do you mean literally running out on the ground?

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it could be the thermostat stuck closed but that doesn't completely explain the heater not blowing warm air. When it's overheating are the upper and lower radiator hoses hot, how about the radiator itself?